Moving RAID1 of ServeRAID M5014 to mdadm
We have an old server, which installed a RAID card ServerRAID M5014 (LSI megaraid compatible), running RAID1 with 2 hard disks. Recently this server was broken, and we found a new server to operate the RAID1. In the process we did not carefully check everything. We just naively moved the 2 hard disks from the old server to the new server, and then powered on the new server. But suddenly we were aware that the new server (Debian Linux 11.10, Kernel 5.4.136) has mdadm installed (version 4.1-11), and mdadm automatically brought up the RAID1 of the 2 hard disks. It looks like that the RAID1 runs without problem. So we feel that we are very lucky.
Now /proc/mdadm shows the status as following:
Personalities : [raid1] 
md126 : active raid1 sdb[1] sda[0]
      975585280 blocks super external:/md127/0 [2/2] [UU]
      
md127 : inactive sdb[1](S) sda[0](S)
      2354608 blocks super external:ddf
       
unused devices: <none>

Currently we mounted /dev/md126 and use it without problem. But we are curious about /dev/md127. Does it come from the zombie configuration of the RAID card of the old server ? Will it affect the current RAID1 system ? Can we just remove it ?
Here are the details of /dev/md126 and /dev/md127:
# mdadm --detail /dev/md126
/dev/md126:
         Container : /dev/md/ddf0, member 0
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 975585280 (930.39 GiB 999.00 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 975585280 (930.39 GiB 999.00 GB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 2

             State : clean 
    Active Devices : 2
   Working Devices : 2
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : resync

    Container GUID : 49424D20:20202020:10000079:101403C7:5375F3E9:800AC16A
                  (IBM      05/15/24 11:18:01)
               Seq : 0000037c
     Virtual Disks : 1

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        0        0      active sync   /dev/sda
       1       8       16        1      active sync   /dev/sdb

# mdadm --detail /dev/md127
/dev/md127:
           Version : ddf
        Raid Level : container
     Total Devices : 2

   Working Devices : 2

    Container GUID : 49424D20:20202020:10000079:101403C7:5375F3E9:800AC16A
                  (IBM      05/15/24 11:18:01)
               Seq : 0000037c
     Virtual Disks : 1

     Member Arrays : /dev/md126

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice

       -       8        0        -        /dev/sda
       -       8       16        -        /dev/sdb

Thanks for your suggestion.
T.H.Hsieh
